# Making emacs/AucTeX open Acrobat on Windows

Tags: windows, emacs, adobe-acrobat, latex, auctex

How can I configure emacs 24 (with AucTeX) on MS windows so that I can bind a key to
`compile the latex document in the active buffer and then open the resulting pdf in acrobat`?

Can the same technique be used to open the PDF in Google Chrome?

Comment: I know that Acrobat locks the PDF while open and wont sync properly, but I am restricted by workstation policy to use that as my PDF viewer.

Comment: Please don't include information about your problem in comments. It's hard to find. Edit your question instead.